# Yarn installed through brew but when I find yarn version it came a error

Tags: yarnpkg

yarn -v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/sadeepa/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.3.1.cjs'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.12.1

[image: 1]

Any one please help? Thanks

I want to reinstall yarn because of some problems then I tried to uninstall all the yarn things and install again so I get errors

Answer (score -1):

Hi I have got the same problem

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx:~/yarn
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.3.1.cjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

and I found the file named .yarnrc.yml and remove it

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx:~$ cat .yarnrc.yml
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.3.1.cjs
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx:~$ rm .yarnrc.yml
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx:~$ yarn
yarn install v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 0.07s.
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx:~$ yarn -v
1.22.19
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. This is just reverting back to Yarn v1 from the expected v3.3.1.